# how to use if and else in react template in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an application with react with es2015,and this is my code :

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {


    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            count : 1
        };

    };

   render (){

        return <div onClick={this._handleclick.bind(this)}>

          Clicks: {this.state.count}

        </div>

    }
    _handleclick (){

        this.setState({count : this.state.count + 1});

    }
}

export default App;
```

my problem is i want an if and else statement in my render function...
i want when count equal 1 an `<h1>hii</h1>` tag show and when count not equal 1 an `<h2>bye</h2>` tag show

Comment: You can only use expressions within JSX, but you can have an if else in normal JS and assign the JSX to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use a ternary expression like `{cond ? okay : notOkay}`
- Use conditionals as in `{cond && okay || notOkay}`
- Use `do` expressions to turn your statements into an expression, with `{ do { if (cond) { okay } else { notOkay } } }`
- Pre-allocate a variable outside of the JSX template and just place that in your expression `{result}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {count: 1};
    },
    handleclick: function() {
        this.setState({count : this.state.count + 1});
    },
    render: function() {
    let comp;
    if(this.state.count === 1) {
        comp = <h1>Hii</h1>;
    } else {
        comp = <h2>Bye</h2>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
            {comp}
      <div onClick={this.handleclick}>

          Clicks: {this.state.count}

        </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I have written the code in ES5 script style. You can do the same in ES6 style that you have adopted by just adding

```
let comp;
    if(this.state.count === 1) {
        comp = <h1>Hii</h1>;
    } else {
        comp = <h2>Bye</h2>;
    }
```

in you `render()` function above return and rendering the component as `{comp}`. I guess this is what you want.